# Why is `ISomeInterface<Derived>` not `ISomeInterface<Base>` in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core

This question must've been asked before, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm struggling to find an answer to this.

Say we have an abstract class called `Base`, and we have a class that inherits from it, called `Derived`.

Considering that, I don't understand why the following condition in the `if` clause doesn't evaluate to `true`?!

```cs
ISomeInterface<Derived> foo = ...;
if (foo is ISomeInterface<Base>) // => false - but why?!
{
    // Blah blah...
}
```

While this would:

```cs
Derived foo = ...;
if (foo is Base) // true
{
    // Blah blah...
}
```

I'd appreciate it if you point me in the right direction.

Comment: An `IList<Orange>` shouldn't be treated as an `IList<Fruit>` because it's still inherently a container of oranges but an `IList<Fruit>` can `.Add(new Apple())`.

Comment: Your question has a false premise. It _would_ be true if `ISomeInterface` was declared as `interface ISomeInterface<out T>`. `IEnumerable<string>` _is_ a kind of `IEnumerable<object>`.